# How to write function's output on multiple line in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, file-writing

I want that my function write multiple lines in a text file but there is only one. I tried to make a loop but nothing changed. Please, help.

Here's my code:

````
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
const num = prompt('myquestion : ');

let path = "mypath"
var x = (Number(num));




function run() {
     for (let ligne = 0; ligne < x; ligne++) {
        fs.writeFileSync(path, "mytext");
    };
};



function gen(length) {
    var result = '';
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
}



run()
console.log("mytext");```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fs.appendFileSync` instead of `fs.writeFileSync`,ALSO  use end of line so that cursor moves to new line while appending .Use [os.EOL](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_eol)

```
var os = require("os");

    function run() {
         for (let ligne = 0; ligne < x; ligne++) {
            fs.appendFileSync(path, "mytext"+os.EOL);
        };
    };
```

Comment: Thanks you so much  for your answer, you helped me a lot. Have a nice day !